# Run python script from bash into Terminal not running

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm trying to run the following bash script on my raspberry pi:

```
#!/bin/bash

python Testing.py
```

It gives me two options: "Execute" and "Execute in Terminal".  Execute works no problem, it produces a CSV that I'm testing.   When I use "Execute in Terminal" though, the script doesn't run (I also have some print statements in there that don't print).  The terminal window is titled "LXTerminal".

Am I missing something?  My goal is to launch the script in a terminal window so it can produce print statements etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Why cant you call the python script directly?

Comment: i guess I could?  how do I do that...?  I'm trying to make this super simple for someone else, so they can simply double click something..

Comment: Yeah, he means why not just execute `python Testing.py` in a terminal.  Seems like the best option, only thing is that it's not as simple for the other person -- they need to know what to do other than just double clicking an executable file.  

Things to check: Are both scripts executable?  And I assume they're both  in the same directory, like both on the Desktop?  What is your shebang on your python script?  Might as well make it `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because I've never done such a thing on a raspberry pi, what happens when you execute this command:
`lxterminal -l -e 'python Testing.py ; /usr/bin/python '`


If it opens a terminal and executes the python script, perhaps you can put that in the bash script.

Comment: See the answer provided here: https://superuser.com/questions/906479/how-to-keep-the-terminal-open-after-executing-a-c-program

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`xterm -e 'python /path/to/my/script.py'`

or if xfce

`xfce4-terminal -e '/path/to/my/script.py'`

I just can't figure out how to keep terminal open when the scipt is complete.

Terminal is closed after script run.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod 755 "file path/filename`. I think this should help as it is used to change the file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and the problem was that my python command was an alias to the executable. When I replaced it with python3, it worked.